# Transient Negative voltage on NMOS causing channel to open?

Tags: mosfet, nmos, transient

This is my first post here. I am an electrical engineer looking to cure my madness because a 2N7002 NMOS is doing things I cannot explain. If you look into the attachments, you will see some screen shots of a schematic, simulation plots, and real scope plots of this issue.

INTENDED DESIGN:
A push button controller to turn on and off power to a system that can also be turned on when plugging in a USB cable. We can trick the push button controller by pulling the PB_L line down when you plug in a USB charging cable. This part is working well, and the system turns on when a USB source is plugged in. The combination of C123, R84a and Q15 create a timer that pulls the PB_L line low for as long as the RC curve remains above the Vgs threshold of the 2N7002 mosfet. This ends up being about a second of time or in other words, plugging in USB looks like someone pressed the button for about a second. The push button controller has a 100k internal pullup on pin 2 to a regulated 1.9V supply from the VSYS supply.

UNINTENDED DESIGN:
When unplugging the USB, the 5V charge (USB is 5V) from the C123 capacitor discharges backwards through the rest of the circuitry. The pulls current from ground through R84a creating a negative voltage on USB_ON_H which is the gate for the NMOS. This means that Vgs is negative. The simulations show that this voltage could spike down to ~ -5V but in reality the spikes are only dropping to about -700mV. For this reason I added in the diode in a second simulation to clamp this voltage such that the result of the simulation more closely matches what I see on my PCB.

MADNESS BEGINS:
Notice how in the simulation the negative transient has no effect on the PB_L signal. This is expected because a negative Vgs should not trigger the NMOS. However, in my circuity, the negative transient is somehow opening up the channel and pulling the PB_L line to ground.

SEARCHING FOR CLUES:
I tried resolving this by several means. I change the pull up on PB_L from and Internal to and external to VSYS... Nothing. I tried adding capacitance on Vusb to ground to try to slow down the discharge,,, nothing. I tried changing the RC timer to see if it would affect the results and it did change the timing but PB_L was still getting pulled low. This was still affecting me on an emotional level.

HYPOTHESIS:
I think that maybe instead of current flowing through R84a to create the negative voltage, it may be flowing from the SOURCE to the GATE. This could maybe open the channel causing this issue. The other thing I suspect could be the VSYS voltage having a transient when changing from battery to USB power. I haven't seen VSYS bounce around in my scope plots.

TLDR; My NMOS is triggering with a negative Vgs and it makes me sad..

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the sharp negative transient at the gate is being coupled capacitively to Q15's drain, via \$C_{DG}\$ within the transistor. It can momentarily bring PB_L with it.

This could be mitigated by slowing the rise and fall of gate potential, with a series resistance, R1 here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI9nTT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>